# Boolean function for clean predicate?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a method which is something like

```
void getCalled(Predicate<Integer> predicate, List<Integer> lst){
   lst.stream().filter(predicate).forEach(...);
}
```

The thing is, for this predicate I will have exactly two choices, which are negations of each other. So the predicates are:

```
public class Helper {
   public static boolean doesExist(int x){
    return ..
   }

   public static boolean doesNotExist(int x){
     return !doesExist();
   }
}
```

Now in the caller I have confusion, which is, should I extract this

```
void caller(){
  List<Integer> lst = ...
  getCalled(lst, Helper::doesExist);
  getCalled(lst, Helper::doesNotExist);
}
```

The issue, I am not sure having extra code for `Helper::doesNotExist` is a good design practice since its just calling the negation of `doesExist`, something like:

```
void caller(){
  List<Integer> lst = ...
  getCalled(lst, Helper::doesExist);
  getCalled(lst, x -> !Helper.doesExist(x)); //Ugly
}
```

At the same time, this is the cleanest way to submit a predicate to the `getCalled` method, by having two different predicates, `doesExist` and `doesNotExist`.

Any idea

Comment: The JDK in places includes methods which are simple negations of each other, for example `Objects::isNull` and `Objects::nonNull` (whose javadoc suggests they are intended for use as `Predicate`s). The JDK isn't perfect but this could be one point in favour of that approach.

Answer (score 2):

Java streams can be collected into so called partitions

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> partitions = 
        lst.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Helper::doesExist));
```

The `Map` now contains two lists, one list of the "existing" elements with the key `true`:

```
partitions.get(true).forEach(...);
```

and a list with the "non-existing" with the key `false`:

```
partitions.get(false).forEach(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's reasonable to ask whether a method that simply negates another should be written, because we often want to avoid duplicating logic. In your example though, the two are so simple that I wouldn't worry about their implementations (and therefore behavior) drifting apart in the future.

Having separate methods `Helper::doesExist` and `Helper::doesNotExist` is good practice in my opinion, because it's easy to read and therefore reason about.

Another option if you're running JDK11 is to [use `Predicate.not`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)).

```
void caller(){
  List<Integer> lst = ...
  getCalled(lst, Helper::doesExist);
  getCalled(lst, not(Helper::doesExist));
}
```

I still think that separate methods are easier to read.